# How do I convert camera coordinates to world coordinates in Moveit using tf2?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone, I would like to convert my object detection pose estimation coordinates to world coordinates so that I can send a pose_target msg to my robotic arm in Moveit. But I do not know what is the first step I should take to perform the task.

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 ros-melodic using an intel realsense D435 depth camera for object detection and pose estimation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414952/how-do-i-convert-camera-coordinates-to-world-coordinates-in-moveit-using-tf2?/) by [RowBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/146276/rowbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2023-05-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bluegiraffe-sc](https://answers.ros.org/users/69377/bluegiraffe-sc/) on 2023-05-22**:
You should use the [`tf2`](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials) package, that can help you managing the transformation between reference frames.

Is your camera already integrated in ROS, or that is your question?

**Comment by [RowBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/146276/rowbot/) on 2023-05-23**:
Yes my camera is already integrated in ROS, I have a object detection topic /aricc_dl_detection/dlObjectDetection/dl_output which gives me the position of the object detected as a geometry_msgs/Point. I notice my target_pose_from_req.pose will always give the same coordinates.

Here is what I did using the tf2 package:

```
    // Construct a PoseStamped message using the detected object's position
    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped target_pose_from_cam;
    target_pose_from_cam.header.frame_id  = "camera_frame";
    target_pose_from_cam.pose.position.x = point.x;
    target_pose_from_cam.pose.position.y = point.y;
    target_pose_from_cam.pose.position.z = point.z;

    // Transform the PoseStamped message to the base frame
    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped target_pose_from_req = buffer_.transform(
    target_pose_from_cam, req.base_frame);

    // Return the transformed pose in the service response
    res.pose = target_pose_from_req.pose
```

**Comment by [bluegiraffe-sc](https://answers.ros.org/users/69377/bluegiraffe-sc/) on 2023-05-29**:
Sorry for the late response. What do you mean by *"always the same coordinates"*?
Is `target_pose_from_req.pose` always giving you a set of values, regardless of changes in the scenario? If so, which are these values? Or do you mean that it is returning the same values you have in `target_pose_from_cam`?

I think that posting or linking the full script (or a larger part of it, at least) might help.

**Comment by [RowBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/146276/rowbot/) on 2023-05-29**:
Apologies for the confusion. It seems that I forgot to run a node that allows the dynamic storage of the target_pose_from_cam in points. As a result, the transform remains constant. Here is the link to the code for my frame transformation: [Code](https://season-cloak-2a7.notion.site/Code-aaa1e37398844affa8007739183ceef4)

**Comment by [bluegiraffe-sc](https://answers.ros.org/users/69377/bluegiraffe-sc/) on 2023-05-31**:
Glad you solved!

Maybe you should add the actual problem as an answer, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that I forgot to run a node that allows the dynamic storage of the target_pose_from_cam in points. As a result, the transform remains constant. Here is the link to the code for my frame transformation: [Code](https://season-cloak-2a7.notion.site/Code-aaa1e37398844affa8007739183ceef4)

---

Originally posted by [RowBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/146276/rowbot/) with karma: 35 on 2023-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0